# Override Community Controller Not Wroking

Tags: php, html

This is My Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
 <modules>
        <Modulename_PrintPdf>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Modulename_PrintPdf>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <ordermanager>
                <rewrite>
                    <observer>Modulename__PrintPdf_Model_Observer</observer>
                </rewrite>
            </ordermanager>
        </models>
    </global>

     <admin>
        <routers>
            <ordermanager>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                   <Modulename__PrintPdf before="Fooman_OrderManager">Modulename__PrintPdf</Modulename__PrintPdf>
                     </modules>
                </args>
            </ordermanager>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

This is My controller in local folder

```
Mage::log("override");
require('Fooman/OrderManager/controllers/Sales/OrderManagerController.php');

class Modulename__PrintPdf_OrderManagerController extends Fooman_OrderManager_Sales_OrderManagerController
{

        public function indexAction()
            {
                Mage::log("hello"); 
            }

}
```

this is my true file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Modulename__PrintPdf>
            <active>false</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Fooman_OrderManager/>
            </depends>
        </Modulename_PrintPdf>
    </modules>
</config>
```

but now working

Answer (score 2):

I think It's because of the two underscores between Modulename and PrintPdf, you should have Modulename_PrintPdf.

Answer (score 1):

Your class needs to match the request path of:

```
site.com/{fooman frontname}/sales/ordermanager/index
--------------------------{                         }
```

Which means that your class needs to be `Modulename__PrintPdf_Sales_OrderManagerController` and in the proper location.

Answer (score 1):

Follow bellow steps

Step : 1 (app\etc\modules\Modulename_PrintPdf.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Modulename_PrintPdf>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Fooman_OrderManager/>
            </depends>
        </Modulename_PrintPdf>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Step : 2 (app\code\local\Modulename\PrintPdf\etc\config.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
 <modules>
        <Modulename_PrintPdf>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Modulename_PrintPdf>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <ordermanager>
                <rewrite>
                    <observer>Modulename_PrintPdf_Model_Observer</observer>
                </rewrite>
            </ordermanager>
        </models>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <ordermanager>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Modulename_PrintPdf before="Fooman_OrderManager">Modulename_PrintPdf</Modulename_PrintPdf>
                     </modules>
                </args>
            </ordermanager>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

Step : 3 (app\code\local\Modulename\PrintPdf\Sales\OrderManagerController.php)

```
<?php
require('Fooman/OrderManager/controllers/Sales/OrderManagerController.php');

class Modulename_PrintPdf_Sales_OrderManagerController extends Fooman_OrderManager_Sales_OrderManagerController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        Mage::log("hello"); 
    }

}
```

Comment: thx but it still not working after adding sales